# Issue an error when item is used outside itemize or enumerate

Tags: errors, enumerate, itemize, compilation-error

I sometimes erroneously type `\item` outside `itemize` or `enumerate`. It would be nice if LaTeX can help me catch such an error. Sometimes it correctly does so and issues an error

```
Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment
```

However, sometimes it fails to catch this error and seems to silently ignore the `\item`. For instance, it happens when I'm in a theorem environment. See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\item
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Compilation would silently succeed, which is *not* desirable.

Comment: In LaTeX, the `enumerate`, `itemize`, and many theorem-like environments are all built on the very-low-level `list` and `trivlist` environments.

Comment: You could (I guess) patch every environment which uses `trivlist` and where you don't want `\item` so `\item` gave an error when used in the body of the environment. But I fear it would be a perpetual struggle.

Comment: @Mico Thanks very much for the info. I've slightly edited the question to make it more accurate.

Answer (score 4):

Classically, theorems, verbatim, center, etc were all defined as single item lists so, as you note, `\item` does not give an error.

That would be fixable but if you use the new (experimental) code for pdf tagging, such environments are not build on the list code (so they do not get tagged as lists in the accessibility pdf structure).

```
\DocumentMetadata{
testphase={phase-III},
}
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\item
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Would give an error that `\item` is not in a list.

Currently the actual error message is broken so you get an internal command undefined error first, but that will get fixed:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \__block_item_instance:n 
                                    
l.9 \end
        {thm}
? 

! LaTeX Error: Unknown message 'item-in-nonlist' for module '__block'.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 \end
        {thm}
?
```

The broken error  messgage is reported here

https://github.com/latex3/tagging-project/issues/35

I guess Ulrike was planning a similar answer to this:-)

Comment: +1 for "That would be fixable but..." Actually, just in case somebody thinks that this would be easy to accomplish, please disabuse them of this notion. :-)

Comment: you could use the new block code also without tagging: `testphase=block` (but with the same broken error message).

Answer (score 3):

Since theorem-like environments are built on the low-level `list` and `trivlist` environments, and since `list` and `trivlist` environments occur in lots and lots of places in LaTeX's kernel code, disabling instances of `\item` outright if they're encountered outside of `enumerate` and `itemize` environments would require an extensive rewrite of the LaTeX kernel. I will assert that this is something that should be avoided at nearly all cost -- at least by anyone who isn't part of the LaTeX3 development team.

What to do? If you can employ LuaLaTeX to compile the document, you could add some preprocessor-like code (in the preamble) to check "on the fly" if the input stream contains instances of `\item` and, if so, to issue a suitable warning message.

The code proposed below is programmed to handle the case that `enumerate` and `itemize` environments can be nested.

[image]

The proposed code also assumes that there's only one instance per input line (at most) of `\begin{enumerate}`, `\end{enumerate}`, `\begin{itemize}`, `\end{itemize}`, or `\item`. I trust that this isn't much of a constraint.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,xcolor}

%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
inItemizeOrEnumerate = 0 -- initialize with value '0' ("false")

function FlagLonelyItems ( s )
  if s:find ( '\\begin%s-{itemize}' ) or 
     s:find ( '\\begin%s-{enumerate}' ) then
       inItemizeOrEnumerate = inItemizeOrEnumerate + 1 -- increment the counter
  elseif s:find ( '\\end%s-{itemize}' ) or 
     s:find ( '\\end%s-{enumerate}' ) then
       inItemizeOrEnumerate = inItemizeOrEnumerate - 1 -- decrement the counter
  elseif s:find ( '\\item' ) then
     if inItemizeOrEnumerate==0 then -- check if inside 'enumerate' or 'itemize' env.
       return ( '\\ \\begin{center}' ..
                '\\color{red} \\upshape Found a lonely item.' ..
                '\\end{center}' .. 
                s )
     end
  end
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% LaTeX-side code: utility macros to activate/deactivate the Lua function
\newcommand\FlagLonelyItemsOn{
   \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback ( 
   "process_input_buffer" , FlagLonelyItems , "FlagLonelyItems" )}}
\newcommand\FlagLonelyItemsOff{ 
   \directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback ( 
   "process_input_buffer" , "FlagLonelyItems" )}}


\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\FlagLonelyItemsOn % Activate the Lua function
   
\begin {enumerate}
  \item x
\begin{itemize}
  \item y
\end {itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{thm}
  \item z
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why the downvote???

Comment: no idea, but at least 1-1=0 :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks!

Comment: plus another +1 is 1 :-)

Comment: @Zarko - Thanks as well!